# Electorate badge is not awarded

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, electorate-badge

Regarding the [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badge. I noticed that I have voted above 600 and 50% of which are on questions. But no such badge is awarded in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You havent voted on 600 question still.

As per its description you should atleast `Voted on 600 questions` while you have voted on 471 question.

- Vote on 600 questions
- Have at least 25% of your total number of votes cast (questions and answers) be on questions
- Comment votes do not count

This seems to be an especially confusing badge, so here are some examples to address cases commonly complained about on MSO. `Total` is just the total number of votes cast (`Questions` + `Answers`) and `Ratio` is the total number of votes cast that are on questions.

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────────┐  
│ Questions │ Answers │ Total │ Ratio │ Electorate awarded? │  
├───────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤  
│       600 │    2400 │  3000 │   20% │   No; ratio too low │  
│       201 │     401 │   602 │  ~33% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       599 │       0 │   599 │  100% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       600 │       0 │   600 │  100% │                 Yes │  
│       500 │     500 │  1000 │   50% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       650 │     650 │  1300 │   50% │                 Yes │  
└───────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

[From existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/252602).

Comment: Question Edited. The issue is in `StackOverflow`.

Comment: @tailorBird rules applied same for all the sites

Answer (score 1):

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

You didn't complete the first part. You have voted >600 times, but you need 600 times on questions.

Take a look at [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930544/tailorbird); as of now, it says you voted 471 times on questions, although you've voted `641 + 12 = 653` times total.

---

This is an exact formula for the number of times you need to vote on questions, depending on the number of times you voted on answers:

```
600 + ⌊1/4(answer vote count - 1800)⌋
```

where `⌊x⌋` is the floor function